# How to terminate from a method that returns a string

Tags: java

If i have a void method, one of the ways to terminate from it under certain condition is using the keyword "return", something like this

```
    public void test() {
     if (condition()) {
         return;
     }
    }
```

What if i have a method that returns string

```
public String test() {
 if (condition()) {
     //what to do here to terminate from the method, and i do not want to use the null or "" return
 }
}
```

Comment: you can throw exception

Comment: If this is something that you're genuinely interested in doing, consider that your declared return type may not be the most appropriate one. You might also want to look at the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: Yeah, only use the exception if you really have an exceptional case. Otherwise you should test for the condition outside of the method.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to terminate a method's execution without returning a value is by throwing an exception.

```
public String test() throws SomeException {
  if (condition()) {
    throw new SomeException ();
  }
  return someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Guava Optional or Java 8 Optional you can do this.

```
public Optional<String> test() {
   if (condition()) {
       return Optional.absent();
   }

  ...
  return Optional.of("xy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop method execution by throwing exception ,but better approach will be like you return some value like if you dont want to return "" , than you can use something like "noResult" or "noValue" and you can check with it in caller

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        test();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("method has not returned anything");
    }
}

public static String test() throws Exception {
    try {
        if (true) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return "";
}
```